# Give a good example of 3-tier architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/three_tier_architecture.aspx

Does this website give a good example on 3-tier architecture? I thought it was a good example, but seemed like a few of the 1 star raters actually said that it's not a good practice.

So I was wondering can any of you give me an example of a good 3-tier app?

Sorry I think I might be unclear, I am looking for codes :) (in OOP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider StackOverflow.  It has a data tier containing all the user and question/answer information.  It has a fairly sophisticated business-logic tier for managing things like user permissions based upon reputation score, voting questions and answers up/down, closing/reopening questions, handing out badges, and so on.  And it has a functional if slightly dated HTML and JavaScript user-interface tier that people use to create and edit their questions and answers, among other things.

Comment: Careful with your wording `tier` is not the same as `layer.`

Comment: I assume the OP wants a simple open source example so he can learn from it.

Comment: Actually I just started learning a little about 3-tier application in school, and I have a project to do now. Based on what my teacher wants, he said he hope to see a 3-tier application done (OOP) Struggling real bad now, lol. and @CodeInChaos yep, I need to see an good actual example, have been googling for the past few hours non-stop